failed installing opencv4node
i would want to make a node.js project with opencv but i failed to install opencv4node. Can someone help me please .Here are the errors I encountered
i tried installing chocolatey, i saw it in someone's answer 's post but it doesn't work
npm install --save opencv4nodejs --build-from-source

PS D:\learnnode> npm install --save @u4/opencv4nodejs --force
npm warn using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm warn cleanup   [
npm warn cleanup     '\\\\?\\D:\\learnnode\\node_modules\\@u4\\opencv- 
build',
npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 
'D:\learnnode\node_modules\@u4\opencv-build\script\deps\jsr.io'] {
npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm warn cleanup       path: 'D:\\learnnode\\node_modules\\@u4\\opencv- 
build\\script\\deps\\jsr.io'
npm warn cleanup     }
npm warn cleanup   ]
npm warn cleanup ]
npm error code 1
npm error path D:\learnnode\node_modules\@u4\opencv4nodejs
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@10.2.0
npm error gyp info using node@22.9.0 | win32 | x64
npm error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.0 found at 
"C:\Users\ideal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
npm error gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.11.35312.102) found at:
npm error gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2022\Community"
npm error gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm error gyp info spawn 
C:\Users\ideal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm error gyp info spawn args [
npm error gyp info spawn args 'D:\\learnnode\\node_modules\\node- 
gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'msvs',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args 
'D:\\learnnode\\node_modules\\@u4\\opencv4nodejs\\build\\config.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'D:\\learnnode\\node_modules\\node- 
gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\ideal\\AppData\\Local\\node- 
gyp\\Cache\\22.9.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm error gyp info spawn args '- 
Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\ideal\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\22.9.0',
npm error gyp info spawn args '- 
Dnode_gyp_dir=D:\\learnnode\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '- 
Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\ideal\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node- 
gyp\\\\Cache\\\\22.9.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm error gyp info spawn args '- 
Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\learnnode\\node_modules\\@u4\\opencv4nodejs',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm error gyp info spawn args 
'D:\\learnnode\\node_modules\\@u4\\opencv4nodejs\\build',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm error gyp info spawn args ]
npm error gyp: Call to 'node ./bin/install.js OPENCV4NODEJS_DEFINES' 
returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load 
binding.gyp
npm error gyp ERR! configure error
npm error gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> 
(D:\learnnode\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:317:18)
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"D:\\learnnode\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm error gyp ERR! cwd D:\learnnode\node_modules\@u4\opencv4nodejs
npm error gyp ERR! node -v v22.9.0
npm error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.2.0
npm error gyp ERR! not ok
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: 
C:\Users\ideal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-23T19_34_06_698Z- 
debug-0.log


Did you ever get this working?

It seems this error is caused by installing the package using "new" versions of node/npm. There are a lot of issues talking about this problem on the project's Github repository, for example this one. Workarounds that might or might not lead to success include downgrading npm, installing a dependency of opencv4nodejs first, disabling automatic opencv.js building and installing node-gyp for building opencv.js automatically. You might want to search the Github issues for your error and read the discussions there for further information.
However, as the project's README states, it is no longer maintained and you probably shouldn't use it. Instead, it recommends using this fork, which provides rather detailed installation instructions.

So i tried installing it like this > npm install --save @u4/opencv4nodejs
and it literally says
npm error code 1
npm error path D:\learnnode\node_modules@u4\opencv4nodejs
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@10.2.0
npm error gyp info using node@22.9.0 | win32 | x64
npm error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.0 found at "C:\Users\ideal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"

Is that the full error? As far as I can tell there's no actual error message in your comment, just info logs from node-gyp.
Additionally, I see you've opened a rather nondescript issue on the project's Github - you might want to link this question there and vice-versa.

No this isn't the full error, the full error couldn't fit in the comment section.
I don't understand the error message neither .
What do you mean by "wanting to link this question there and vice-versa".?

The last line of the error message points to another log file. Could you have a look at that and see if there's any helpful information in there? If that doesn't help your resolve your problem, please upload it to pastebin or a similar site and link it here. As for linking this question to the Github issue, just include a link to the issue in this Stackoverflow question and a link to the question in the Github issue.

Another thing you could try is disabling autobuild, so the library doesn't try to build opencv itself, which is what node-gyp is used for. For details on how to do this please refer to the Github repo's README.

this is the link to the log file if you can take a look at it. I did and it mostly says that some caches are missing.
logFile

thanks for your advice, i'll try disabling autobuild and let you know when it's done
